# is there any CDN link for extjs reactor

Tags: extjs, extreact

I want to develop extjs-reactor application using extjs-reactor CDN .I have not found any CDN link in extjs site. Is there a CDN link for extjs-reactor and please share with me If there is any extjs-reactor CDN example.

Comment: https://www.sencha.com/blog/the-ext-js-reactor-use-your-favorite-ext-js-components-inside-react/

Answer (score 0):

You can't develop an extjs-reactor application, but you can use the library extjs-reactor with React and [use the ExtJS components](https://docs.sencha.com/extreact/6.6.0/guides/guide_for_extjs_customers.html#guide_for_extjs_customers_-_using_ext_js_components_in_react). There is no CDN link for this, you would have to install it to your React application through NPM, see the [documentation](https://docs.sencha.com/extreact/6.6.0/guides/guide_for_extjs_customers.html#guide_for_extjs_customers_-_guide_for_ext_js_customers) from Sencha.